# is there a way to get a bot to automatically restart if the site crashes

Tags: python, selenium, bots

is there a way to get this bot to automaticly restart if the site crashes and is there a way for the bot to refresh the page if the site doesnt load properly. becsause i cant get an xpath on the refresh and i have no clue how to make the bot restart if it didnt accomplish its goals

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
start_time = time.time()

# my code here



path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)

# open page
driver.get("https://www.usmint.gov/")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="navigation"]/div[3]/ul/li[2]/a')) #PRODUCT S
    )
finally:
# product schedule
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="navigation"]/div[3]/ul/li[2]/a').click()
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="navigation"]/div[3]/ul/li[2]/div/div/ul/li[3]/a')) #2020
    )
finally:
# 2020 product schedule
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="navigation"]/div[3]/ul/li[2]/div/div/ul/li[3]/a').click()
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="4cb2318c15eb72316187ca9691"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/a')) #birth set
    )
finally:
# birth set 2020
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="4cb2318c15eb72316187ca9691"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/a').click()
    '''
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="emailmodalclose"]')) #clear
    )
finally:
# clear email list stupidity
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="emailmodalclose"]').click()
     '''
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div/div[5]/button[1]')) #add to
    )
finally:
# add to bag
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div/div[5]/button[1]").click()# double qoutes?
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mini-cart"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/a')) #checkout
    )
finally:
# checkout
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mini-cart"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/a').click()
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="dwfrm_login_username"]')) #login
    )
finally:
# login
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dwfrm_login_username"]').send_keys("email")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="dwfrm_login_password"]')) #Password
    )
finally:
# password
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dwfrm_login_password"]').send_keys("password")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="checkoutMethodLoginSubmit"]/span')) #checkout as
    )
finally:
# checkout as registered user
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkoutMethodLoginSubmit"]/span').click()
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="dwfrm_billing_paymentMethods_creditCardList"]/option[2]')) #credit card scroll
    )
finally:
# credit card scroll
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dwfrm_billing_paymentMethods_creditCardList"]/option[2]').click()  # .format?
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="dwfrm_billing_paymentMethods_creditCard_month"]/option[2]')) #cc exp m
    )
finally:
# cc exp month
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dwfrm_billing_paymentMethods_creditCard_month"]/option[2]').click()
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="dwfrm_billing_paymentMethods_creditCard_year"]/option[11]')) #cc exp y
    )
finally:
# cc exp year
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dwfrm_billing_paymentMethods_creditCard_year"]/option[11]').click()
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="dwfrm_billing_paymentMethods_creditCard_cvn"]')) #cvv
    )
finally:
# cvv
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dwfrm_billing_paymentMethods_creditCard_cvn"]').send_keys("999")
time.sleep(2)
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="checkoutContinuePaymentDelegator"]')) #continue to final
    )
finally:
# continue to final review
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkoutContinuePaymentDelegator"]').click()
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="formAgreementLabel"]/span')) #terms of use
    )
finally:
# terms of use button
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="formAgreementLabel"]/span').click()
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="submitOrderButton"]')) #Place order
    )
finally:
# place order
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="submitOrderButton"]').click()
    print ("time elapsed: {:.2f}s".format(time.time() - start_time))
    driver.quit()

#if __name__ == '__main__':
#    order(keys)
```

and if you see anything in the code that can be fixed it would be appreciated

Comment: if "restarting the bot" means running the script again, just add a `try except` with a "while True:" around the code and break it when it is completed

Comment: but I don't think that's your real problem, as you have not properly used `try except` in your code. If you just don't add a except clause, it won't do anything when it encounters an error, including the "restart" or re-execution that you want

Comment: yes that would be great... would you be able to give the code for that

Comment: You could while true: try: {put everything here and then a break} except:{print error} instead.

Answer (score 0):

As requested in the comment, this is the simplest but not the ideal way. Since your `try except` clause does not include an `except` clause, they serve no purpose in your code except it just suppress all your `TimeoutException`, which you actually want them as you need to know what error it encounters. To improve this solution, you can consider to split the `try except` clause and re-execute those wait element lines only instead of the whole script.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
start_time = time.time()

# my code here



path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)

while True:
    try:
        # open page
        driver.get("https://www.usmint.gov/")
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="navigation"]/div[3]/ul/li[2]/a')) #PRODUCT S
        )

        # product schedule
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="navigation"]/div[3]/ul/li[2]/a').click()
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="navigation"]/div[3]/ul/li[2]/div/div/ul/li[3]/a')) #2020
        )

        # 2020 product schedule
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="navigation"]/div[3]/ul/li[2]/div/div/ul/li[3]/a').click()
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="4cb2318c15eb72316187ca9691"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/a')) #birth set
        )
        # birth set 2020
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="4cb2318c15eb72316187ca9691"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/a').click()
        '''
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="emailmodalclose"]')) #clear
        )
        # clear email list stupidity
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="emailmodalclose"]').click()
        '''
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div/div[5]/button[1]')) #add to
        )
        # add to bag
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div/div[5]/button[1]").click()# double qoutes?
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mini-cart"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/a')) #checkout
        )
        # checkout
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mini-cart"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/a').click()
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="dwfrm_login_username"]')) #login
        )
        # login
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dwfrm_login_username"]').send_keys("email")
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="dwfrm_login_password"]')) #Password
        )
        # password
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dwfrm_login_password"]').send_keys("password")
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="checkoutMethodLoginSubmit"]/span')) #checkout as
        )
        # checkout as registered user
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkoutMethodLoginSubmit"]/span').click()
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="dwfrm_billing_paymentMethods_creditCardList"]/option[2]')) #credit card scroll
        )
        # credit card scroll
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dwfrm_billing_paymentMethods_creditCardList"]/option[2]').click()  # .format?
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="dwfrm_billing_paymentMethods_creditCard_month"]/option[2]')) #cc exp m
        )
        # cc exp month
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dwfrm_billing_paymentMethods_creditCard_month"]/option[2]').click()
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="dwfrm_billing_paymentMethods_creditCard_year"]/option[11]')) #cc exp y
        )
        # cc exp year
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dwfrm_billing_paymentMethods_creditCard_year"]/option[11]').click()
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="dwfrm_billing_paymentMethods_creditCard_cvn"]')) #cvv
        )
        # cvv
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="dwfrm_billing_paymentMethods_creditCard_cvn"]').send_keys("999")
        time.sleep(2)
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="checkoutContinuePaymentDelegator"]')) #continue to final
        )
        # continue to final review
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="checkoutContinuePaymentDelegator"]').click()
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="formAgreementLabel"]/span')) #terms of use
        )
        # terms of use button
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="formAgreementLabel"]/span').click()
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="submitOrderButton"]')) #Place order
        )
        # place order
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="submitOrderButton"]').click()
        print ("time elapsed: {:.2f}s".format(time.time() - start_time))
        driver.quit()
        break
    except Exception as err:
        print(f"Error: {str(err)}, trying again")
        pass

#if __name__ == '__main__':
#    order(keys)
```